# What could be the possible consequences of default encoding to UTF-8 for a String to Stream conversion?

Tags: java, string, unicode, encoding, inputstream

I need to convert Strings obtained from some API's to InputStream consumed by other API's. The only way is that I convert the String to Stream without knowing the exact encoding. So I assume it to be UTF-8 and it works fine for now. However I would like to know what could be a better solution for this given that I have no way of identifying the the encoding of the source of the string.

Comment: Your question is unclear: do you start with strings or streams? Do you have any documentation for the API that you're sending the stream to?

Comment: I'm starting with streams. Sending it to an api that accepts strings.

Answer (score 3):

There is no good solution to the problem of not knowing the encoding.

Because of this, you must demand that the encoding be explicitly specified, or else use one single agreed-upon encoding that is strictly adhered to.

Also, make sure you use the rare form of the contructor to InputStreamReader that condescends to raise an exception on an encoding error. That is `InputStreamReader(InputStream in, CharsetDecoder dec)`.  The other three are either broken or else infelicitously designed depending on your point of view or purposes, because they suppress encoding errors and render your program unreliable and nonportable.

Be **very** careful about missing errors, especially when you do not know for sure what you are getting — and even if you think you do :).

Answer (score 0):

The possible consequences of applying the incorrect encoding is getting the wrong data out the other end.

The specific consequences will depend on the specific encodings. For example, if you receive a stream of ISO-8859-1 characters, and try to decode using UTF-8, you'll probably get errors due to incorrect sequences. If you start with UTF-16 and assume that it's ISO-8859-1, you'll get twice as many characters as you expect, and every other one will be garbage.

Comment: You won’t always get errors for incorrect sequences. It depends how you decode things.

Answer (score 0):

Encodings are not a property of Strings in Java, they're only relevant when you *convert* between Strings and bytes. If those APIs give you Strings, there is only one point where your program needs to use an encoding, which is when you convert the String back to bytes to be returned by the InputStream. And those "other APIs" of course need to know which encoding to use if they're going to interpret the contents as text data.

Answer (score 0):

To add to the other answers, your deployed application will no longer be portable between Windows and Linux, since these usually have different default encodings.